# MVVM - UserControl Loaded only first time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using ViewModel-first aprroach. In MainWindow.xaml I've set ContentControl where I display my UserControls (Views), by a click on a MenuItem. When I click to display UserControl first time, everything works fine.

But when I click same MenuItem to open It once again, my UserControl displays again but doesn't get loaded anymore, resulting in not having refreshed bindings. Setting my ContentControl's Content to null doesn't resolve issue.

My whole setup is like this:

**1.) App.xaml resource**

```
 <!--DataContext for MainWindow.xaml-->
 <ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Main_VM"/>

 <!--DataTemplate for UserControl-->
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MyViewModel}">
    <Views:MyView />
 </DataTemplate>
```

**2.) MainWindow.xaml, where my ContenControl is located**

```
     <Window x:Class="My.Views.MainWindowView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            DataContext="{StaticResource Main_VM}">
      <Grid>
    
       <!--Menu which opens view on command-->
        <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" IsMainMenu="True" >
          <MenuItem Header="My View" Command="{Binding Show_View}" CommandParameter="1"/>
        </Menu>

       <ContentControl Content="{Binding Display_View}" />
  
       <!--And all other controls, like Menu for opening views on click...-->

      </Grid>
     </Window>
```

**3.) ViewModel for Mainwindow.xaml (inherited from BaseViewModel)**

```
  public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
           //Command for displaying Views
            Show_View = new Relay_Command(Open_view, null);
        }
           
        public ICommand Show_View { get; set; }
    
        private BaseViewModel _display_view;
        public BaseViewModel Display_View
        {
            get { return _display_view; }
            set { _display_view = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
     
        private void Open_view(object parameter)
        {
           
            Display_View = null; //This doesn't help at all!!!

            switch (parameter)
            {
                case "1": 
                 Display_View= new MyViewModel();
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**4.) And my UserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" 
             d:DesignWidth="800">

    <!--Event-->
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
           
            <!--Calling a method on Load (firing only first tme !!)-->
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MethodForRetrievingData" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>

      <!--Controls in UserControl for binding etc...-->

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've tried debugging, but as told, **Loaded event of UserControl happens only once**. I'm out of ideas on this one, looks like my design has a flaw.

**What could be a problem here, maybe I'm missing something like NotifyProperty on UserControl itself?**

Comment: Can you please post the code where`Display_View` is bind to a `content control`? As per you current posted code ` <ContentControl Content="{Binding Show_View}" />` I see Show_View has a binding

Comment: @user1672994, thanks for noticing that, It was a typo, sorry for that - **Display_View** is what is binding to ContentControl. I edited question in ManWindow.xaml, I added a Menu control which opens views too - which is binding to **Show_View**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually unload the view for it to be loaded again. Setting the source property of the `ContentControl`'s `Content` property to `null` just before setting it to another `MyViewModel` won't unload the view. The `DataTemplate` is "cached".

Why don't you call the `MethodForRetrievingData` from the view model itself instead of relying on the view raising a `Loaded` event? You may for example [initialize it asynchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: this is exactly what I figured out, **aDisplayName** pointed me there. I allready changed code to calling **MethodForRetrievingData** from the view model. However- If you wait long enough - around sec or two - when you set ContentControl to null, then View get's Loaded again. Unloading on the other side, strangely, occurs every time....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of displaying a `MyViewModel` object content using template, try display a `MyView` content instead.

So you would have

```cs
        private MyView _display_view;
        public MyView Display_View
        {
            get { return _display_view; }
            set { _display_view = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private void Open_view(object parameter)
        {
           
            Display_View = null; //This doesn't help at all!!!

            switch (parameter)
            {
                case "1": 
                 Display_View= new MyView(); // Or assign a view model here: {DataContext=new MyViewModel()}
                 break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I shouldn't reference View in a viewModel, that is against MVVM.

Comment: The reason we say "shouldn't" not "mustn't" is becaus there are cases you still need to do it. You are calling "MethodForRetrievingData" in the MyView. It seems it is data related, then you are violating your own rule of not mixing data and view. Either move the "MethodForRetrievingData" to the MyViewModel, or consider the whole view is data.

Comment: Isn't that a point of Interactivity dll ? To use It like this in MVVM - have code in ViewModel but connect It with View event in .xaml? I'm confused now. Moving **MethodForRetrievingData** to Viewmodel constructor would not result same as in Load event of UserControl, presentation of UI would become different. That is not what I want.

Comment: Beside that, I think this is not an issue. Issue is that Usercontrol doesn't Load second time alhough I can see It displayed. So moving code to anywhere wouldn't help me - because Load event is not firing anymore, so code doesn't get executed.

Comment: looks like you were right. I'll try to fix It now. Will update on answer If I solve It.

Comment: I don't have the source code on how the datatemplate is working under the hood. My guess is, the MyView is part of the template which is only initiated once when created by the "```ContentControl```", even when ```Display_View``` is ```null```. You can set a breakpoint in 1) ```MethodForRetrievingData```, 2) ```Open_View```. I would expect the breakpoint in ```MEthodForRetrievingData``` could be hit before "```Open_VIew```". I might be wrong.

Comment: I've allready debugged all. Looks like ContentControl caches DataTemplates for a while. Anyway, I removed all Interactivity .dll code and used calling from ViewModel directly, and now It works as expected.Thanks for help, your point got me to a right direction.